# How to move "Re:" & "Fwd:" email received in a shared inbox to a subfolder?

Tags: vba, outlook

All the reply (RE:) and the forward (FWD:) mails received in a shared inbox has to automatically move to an "Ongoing folder".

This code is not working.

```
Private Sub Application_NewMail()

    Dim olNameSpace As NameSpace
    Set olNameSpace = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    Dim olDestFolder As Folder
    Set olDestFolder = olNameSpace.Folders("xxx@gmail.com").Folders("Ongoing")
    
    Dim olLookUpFolder As Folder
    Set olLookUpFolder = olNameSpace.Folders("xxx@gmail.com").Folders("Inbox")

    ' olMail is a Class. Avoid as a variable name
    'Dim olMail As MailItem
    Dim olObj As Object ' Outlook items are not necessarily mailitems
    
    For Each olObj In olLookUpFolder.Items 'loop through Tickets folder to find original mail
    
        If olObj.Class = olMail Then
            
            Set objMail = objItem
            v = objMail.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003")
            If (v = 102) Or (v = 104) Then
                olObj.Move olDestFolder ' move to InProgress folder
                Exit For
            End If
            
        End If
    
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: please give a better description than `When I run this below code its not working`.  What is the error and on which line?

Comment: BigBen- Changed as requested. I'm not able to identify the replay and the forward mails received to the shared inbox to move the ongoing folder. Also I'm not sure how to read the reply and forward code.

Comment: Sorry Scott, I understand your question, but when I run this I'm not getting any error message either it's not working, the reply mails is not moving to the Ongoing folder.

Comment: Have you tried to step through your code?

Comment: Are you processing a folder once? Or do you want to only process new items as they come in? Your code processes the whole folder every time new mail comes in, which is kinda crazy.

Comment: I just want to process **only new items as they come in** and not the whole folder every time.

Comment: Please share the full code.

Comment: I thought I saw NewMailEx code, to look at the item being received, in an answer post. If you still have it, add it to the question post. I suggest the response from Dimitry is not appropriate as it follows your misleading code looking at old received items in a folder rather than the item being received.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, do not use "for each" against a collection that you are modifying  (by calling `MailItem.Move`). Use a down loop.

Secondly, never loop through all items in a folder (you wouldn't use a `SELECT` query in SQL without a `WHERE` clause, would you?) - use `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict:`

```
    set query = "@SQL=(""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003"" = 102) or (""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003"" = 104)"    
    set olItems = olLookUpFolder.Items.Restrict(query)
    for i = olItems.Count to 1 step -1
       set olObj = olItems.Item(i) 
...
```

Comment: Thank you Dmitry

Comment: Can I replace your code insead of this " Set objMail = objItem
      v = objMail.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003")
      If (v = 102) Or (v = 104) Then" is that right?

Comment: `
        If olObj.Class = olMail Then
            
            Set query = "@SQL=(""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003"" = 102) or (""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10810003"" = 104)"
    Set olItems = olLookUpFolder.Items.Restrict(query)
    For i = olItems.Count To 1 Step -1
       Set olObj = olItems.Item(i)
                olObj.Move olDestFolder ' move to InProgress folder
                Exit For`